# Why am I getting out of memory errors only after several runs of my Spark Application?

Tags: apache-spark, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I ran my spark application successfully twice after spinning up a fresh EMR cluster. After running a different Spark Application several times that DOES have out of memory issues, I ran the first spark application again and got out of memory errors.

I repeated this sequence of events three times and it happens every time. What could be happening? Shouldn't Spark free all memory between runs?

Comment: It's difficult to figure out why without some more information about what exactly you're trying to do and maybe a stacktrace on that Out of memory Error.

Answer (score 0):

After a spark program completed, It generates temporary directories and it's remain in the temp directory so after runs several spark applications it might be gives out of memory error. There is some clean up options which can solve this issue.

`spark.worker.cleanup.enabled` (Default value is false),
`spark.worker.cleanup.interval`, `spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl` for more details about these kindly go through this document.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts

Comment: How would this contribute to an out of memory error? I can imagine that it would be more of a disk space issue.

Comment: when this temp directory occupied more memory then its create out of memory issue...What I suggested clear this temp directory then try  to run the program.